# A Royal Flag Of North

Tags: riddle, knowledge, flags

I'm flag that will always fly

Half-crushed snail, and half-grown field

And a now crushed sun drop in between the yield

And spikes to the side to hold me high

Oh, I command ye, what fictional flag am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> Flag of Kingdom of Arendelle (Frozen)

*Half-crushed snail, and half-grown field*

> The colors of the flag depict each of these. The other variant of flag shows a snail like structure.

*And a now crushed sun drop in between the yield*

> The snowflake like structure in the center of the flag

*And spikes to the side to hold me high*

> Spikes at one side of the flag

*Oh, I command ye, what fictional flag am I?*

> [image] and another variant [image]

Comment: Not quite, but it is a  kingdom. The second line is more abstract, think color.

Comment: Haha. That's great! I ll try to write up the answer